# Conditionally append a string in a GitHub actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to use GitHub Actions expressions to concatenate a string conditionally?

E.g. like I'm trying to do in below example.

```yaml
      - name: Release
        uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@v2
        with:
          version: latest
          args: release --rm-dist  ${{ if (startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')) { '--snapshot' }}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the following which would return `-additional-arg` if the condition is satisfied and empty string otherwise:

```
${{ (startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') && '-additional-arg') || '' }}
```

Example:

```yaml
name: Test arguments

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Release
        uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@v2
        with:
          version: latest
          args: release --rm-dist ${{ (startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') && '--snapshot') || '' }}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. If you don't need the else clause like I did, it can even be simpler.

`${{ !startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') && '--snapshot' }}`

Comment: @Marco it would work for the regular commit push, but when you push a tag, it would produce this error `goreleaser release --rm-dist false` which result in `⨯ command failed            error=unknown command "false" for "goreleaser release"`. The `|| ''` gives a default value in case the condition fails (return `false`)

Comment: you are right. I missed that. Thanks for clarifying that here.

Comment: I needed a variable in the conditional arg so I used `format` to add it as well
`${{ matrix.package.version && format('--version {0}', matrix.package.version) || '' }}`